# How to generate a range of timestamps on weekdays at 08:00-16:00+RAND by Zsh/AWK?

Tags: zsh

I am thinking how to generate a range of timestamps on weekdays in 11.11.2017 - 12.12.2017 by ZSH/AWK/... such that each day starts at 08:00 and ends at 16:00+RAND. The day end should have some random ending, etc by variance of 30 min. Expected output example

```
11.11.2017 08:00 - 16:15
12.11.2017 08:00 - 16:03
...
12.12.2017 08:00 - 15:25
```

OS: Debian Stretch

Comment: Do you want one and only one line for each of the week days (do you mean Monday to Friday excluding Sat, Sun?) or just random days in that interval (but limited to "weekdays")?

Comment: With `zsh` see the strftime builtin in the zsh/datetime module for conversion from/to calendar to/from epoch time (fix TZ to UTC0 to avoid issues with DST) and $RANDOM or $((rand())) (in zsh/mathfunc module) for random number generation. GNU awk also has date manipulation functions.

Comment: 2017-11-11 was a Saturday. What do you mean by "weekdays"? (note that rand() should have been rand48() in my comment above).

Answer (score 1):

Use `strftime` in the `zsh/datetime` module to convert a calendar time to Unix epoch (with `-r`) or back. For random number generation, you have `$RANDOM` like in `ksh`, but that's only a 15 bit integer or the `rand48()` math function (in the `zsh/mathfunc` function).

```
#! /bin/zsh -
start=11.11.2017
end=12.12.2017
TZ=UTC0 # timezone doesn't matter here. We use UTC0 to make sure there's
        # DST/change

zmodload zsh/datetime
zmodload zsh/mathfunc

strftime -rs start_t %d.%m.%Y $start
strftime -rs end_t %d.%m.%Y $end

for ((t = start_t; t <= end_t; t += 24*60*60)) {
  strftime -s weekday %u $t
  if ((weekday < 6)) { # Monday to Friday
    strftime -s s '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M' $((t + 8 * 60*60))
    strftime -s e '%H:%M' $((t + 16*60*60 - 15*60 + int(rand48() * 30*60)))
    print $s - $e
  }
}
```

Comment: Confirmed, this answer works as expected!

Comment: How would you add fluctuation by day on the data? For instance, skip one workday, but work another day little more.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영, you could always add some `((rand48() < 0.1)) && continue` to skip one out of 10 days and compensate by working a few more minutes a day on average.